# I have DDR2 ECC RAM but want to find a compatible server

Tags: memory, server

I have the following type of spare 64GB RAM

DDR2 ECC

4GB 2Rx4 PC2-5300P RAM PC2-5300P-555-13-ZZ

[image]

This came with IBM System X3850 M2 which had issues so didn't work as expected

***What I am looking for***

1. Used HP or Dell server
2. Price range $300 or less
3. Two quad core
4. any compatible server  which will work this RAM

***Existing work***

1. tried with my dl580 and dl380 but they were not compatible
2. It also did to work with del power edge r900
3. Searching on google and eBay basically lists RAM only. Not finding any servers that way

Comment: That's DDR2 ECC RAM, so you're looking for an *old* server (think 2007 or older).

Comment: mt36htf51272py-667e1 searching this on eBay lists lot of the same kind but none had a list of compatible servers

Comment: It looks like you should be looking at servers like Dell Power Edge 2XXX The 2790 take PC2-5300R instead of "P". Im not sure what the difference would be for those 2 MEMORY DIMMs. You will have to look that up. Also carefully read this thread:
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19317822 Also googling this: "Dell servers with PC2 ram" produces a lot of good results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HP Dl585 G5 or DL385 G5. These servers use AMD based processors

both of them take PC2_5300 RAM

DL385 G5 Specs
Memory : Up to 128 GB (with PC2-5300 8GB DIMMs). PC2-6400 800MHz DDR2 Select models support 2:1 Bank Interleaving.
4:1 Bank Interleaving (Data saved across 2 pairs of DIMMs) and Node interleaving support (data saved across 2
processors memory sets) also available

http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04286576.pdf

DL 585 G5
PC2-5300 Registered DIMMs at 667 MHz
http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04286140.pdf